# Extracting the leading coefficient of a discriminant

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves, discriminant

Let $p(y)$, $q(y)$ be irreducible polynomials in $y$, of the same degree $d$ (over some field $K$). Assume also that the resultant of $p$ and $q$ is $1$ or $-1$ (not sure if it is necessary here).

I'm interested in finding the leading term (in regard to $x$) of the polynomial disc$[q(y)x-p(y)]$ (the discriminant is in regard to $y$). I tried working on the definition but I'm not sure how to salvage $x$ from the product. Some products of the inverse images of $x$ under $p\div q$ seem to be calculatable but I'm unsure how to connect the parts.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks, I tried using lyx code and it didn't work, now I see why.